# Difference of datetimes in hours, excluding the weekend

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe, where an uniqueID has multiple dates in another column.  I want extract the hours between each date, but ignore the weekend if the next date is after the weekend.  For example, if today is friday at 12 pm,
and the following date is tuesday at 12 pm then the difference in hours between these two dates would be 48 hours.

Here is my dataset with the expected output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"UniqueID": ["A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"],"Date":
["2018-12-07 10:30:00","2018-12-10 14:30:00","2018-12-11 17:30:00",
"2018-12-14 09:00:00","2018-12-18 09:00:00",
"2018-12-21 11:00:00","2019-01-01 15:00:00","2019-01-07 15:00:00"],
"ExpectedOutput": ["28.0","27.0","Nan","48.0","74.0","NaN","96.0","NaN"]})

df["Date"] = df["Date"].astype(np.datetime64)
```

This is what I have so far, but it includes the weekends:

```
df["date_diff"] = df.groupby(["UniqueID"])["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.diff() 
/ np.timedelta64(1 ,'h')).shift(-1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: The output would be the same as the df["date_diff'] but without the weekend hours

Comment: I think numbers in output data.

Comment: @dko512 Friday to Tuesday is 96 hours and the weekend has 48 hours, so why would the difference be 72 and not 48 hours? Anyway, [`np.busday_count`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @a_guest sorry your right

Comment: @jezrael that's my expected output

Comment: @dko512 - I am thinking a lot about better solution, please check edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is floor datetimes for remove `times` and get number of business days between start day + one day and shifted day to `hours3` column by [`numpy.busday_count`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) and then create `hour1` and `hour2` columns for start and end hours if not weekends hours. Last sum all hours columns together:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.sort_values(['UniqueID','Date'])

df["shifted"] = df.groupby(["UniqueID"])["Date"].shift(-1)
df["hours1"] = df["Date"].dt.floor('d') 
df["hours2"] = df["shifted"].dt.floor('d') 

mask = df['shifted'].notnull()
f = lambda x: np.busday_count(x['hours1'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'), x['hours2'])
df.loc[mask, 'hours3'] = df[mask].apply(f, axis=1) * 24

mask1 = df['hours1'].dt.dayofweek < 5
hours1 = df['hours1'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d') - df['Date']
df['hours1'] = np.where(mask1, hours1, np.nan) / np.timedelta64(1 ,'h')

mask1 = df['hours2'].dt.dayofweek < 5
df['hours2'] = np.where(mask1, df['shifted']-df['hours2'], np.nan) / np.timedelta64(1 ,'h')

df['date_diff'] = df['hours1'].fillna(0) + df['hours2'] + df['hours3']
```

---

```
print (df)
  UniqueID                Date ExpectedOutput             shifted  hours1  \
0        A 2018-12-07 10:30:00           28.0 2018-12-10 14:30:00    13.5   
1        A 2018-12-10 14:30:00           27.0 2018-12-11 17:30:00     9.5   
2        A 2018-12-11 17:30:00            Nan                 NaT     6.5   
3        B 2018-12-14 09:00:00           48.0 2018-12-18 09:00:00    15.0   
4        B 2018-12-18 09:00:00           74.0 2018-12-21 11:00:00    15.0   
5        B 2018-12-21 11:00:00            NaN                 NaT    13.0   
6        C 2019-01-01 15:00:00           96.0 2019-01-07 15:00:00     9.0   
7        C 2019-01-07 15:00:00            NaN                 NaT     9.0   

   hours2  hours3  date_diff  
0    14.5     0.0       28.0  
1    17.5     0.0       27.0  
2     NaN     NaN        NaN  
3     9.0    24.0       48.0  
4    11.0    48.0       74.0  
5     NaN     NaN        NaN  
6    15.0    72.0       96.0  
7     NaN     NaN        NaN
```

First solution was removed with 2 reasons - was not accurate and slow:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01','2018-01-01', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({"UniqueID": np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFGHIJ'), size=100),
                   "Date": np.random.choice(dates, size=100)})
print (df)
```

---

```
def old(df):
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
    df = df.sort_values(['UniqueID','Date'])

    df["shifted"] = df.groupby(["UniqueID"])["Date"].shift(-1)

    def f(x):
        a = pd.date_range(x['Date'],  x['shifted'], freq='T')
        return ((a.dayofweek < 5).sum() / 60).round()


    mask = df['shifted'].notnull()
    df.loc[mask, 'date_diff'] = df[mask].apply(f, axis=1)  
    return df
```

---

```
def new(df):
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
    df = df.sort_values(['UniqueID','Date'])

    df["shifted"] = df.groupby(["UniqueID"])["Date"].shift(-1)
    df["hours1"] = df["Date"].dt.floor('d') 
    df["hours2"] = df["shifted"].dt.floor('d') 

    mask = df['shifted'].notnull()
    f = lambda x: np.busday_count(x['hours1'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'), x['hours2'])
    df.loc[mask, 'hours3'] = df[mask].apply(f, axis=1) * 24

    mask1 = df['hours1'].dt.dayofweek < 5
    hours1 = df['hours1'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d') - df['Date']
    df['hours1'] = np.where(mask1, hours1, np.nan) / np.timedelta64(1 ,'h')

    mask1 = df['hours2'].dt.dayofweek < 5
    df['hours2'] = np.where(mask1, df['shifted'] - df['hours2'], np.nan) / np.timedelta64(1 ,'h')

    df['date_diff'] = df['hours1'].fillna(0) + df['hours2'] + df['hours3']
    return df
print (new(df))
print (old(df))
```

---

```
In [44]: %timeit (new(df))
22.7 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [45]: %timeit (old(df))
1.01 s ± 8.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This makes sense to me, I really appreciate the time you took answering the question.  For someone still learning the language it means a lot to me.

Comment: @dko512 - It was really hard for me, but I like not easy solutions :)

Comment: sorry ignore the comments I posted earlier, i was looking at the wrong column